# Dependency graphs in ConTeXt

Tags: tikz-pgf, context

Have anyone tried using `tikz-dependency` with ConTeXt? http://danielepighin.net/cms/software/tikz-dependency

Can anyone recommend other ways to create dependency graphs in ConTeXt?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You could do it in plain TikZ, see for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41725/dependency-diagrams-using-tikz

Comment: I just looked at the code and it is not possible to use it in ConTeXt. However, it is relatively easy to port the code to ConTeXt. It should also be possible to write the code in a style so that it is usable both in LaTeX and ConTeXt (and some of the other tikz packages do). I would suggest getting in touch with the author to ask if he/she would be willing to make such a change.