# Compact database schema representation in latex

Tags: tables, tkz-graph

I am trying to create a compact database schema similar to the one presented [Here](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=93bf18eb49a84443386f06a02da3be1ca07186f7)
and here is a screenshot for that :

[image]

I am on two column setting too and I looked at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296948/creating-a-relational-database-schema) post but it is not as compact as the one in the picture.

Comment: Welcome! Please provide us with a minimal working example demonstrating a specific problem you want help with. Right now, your post just expects somebody to do-this-complicated-thing-for-you, which is not really how the site works. Sometimes you might get lucky, especially if what you want includes something cute. But otherwise, you need to make a start yourself. The post you linked seems a good basis. Try to adapt it. If you run into a particular problem, you'll find people very willing to help. Or there are people you can hire to create these things, if you don't want to be bothered with it.